How to stop logs in catalina.out
I've implemented Log4j2 for a Spring Boot web application (WAR file) on Tomcat 9. The logs are currently being generated in the specified path in Log4j2 as well as in catalina.out. To stop the logs from appearing in catalina.out, I tried to exclude the following dependency in pom.xml:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

After excluding this dependency, logs are not being generated in either file, and I am receiving the following error:
Error:
2027-05-07 02:17:13.341 INFO 584555 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2027-05-07 02:17:13.346 INFO 584555 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2027-05-07 02:17:13.349 INFO 584555 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Then, I removed the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency as well, but the same error persists. If I set the stdout stream to /dev/null in catalina.sh, logs from other applications running on Tomcat are not generated.
I have the following files:
log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATH">${env:LOG_PATH:-./var/log/restapi/}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_FILE_NAME">${env:LOG_FILE_NAME:-restapi.log}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_APP_LEVEL">${env:LOG_APP_LEVEL:-info}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_ROTATE_SIZE">${env:LOG_ROTATE_SIZE:-1 MB}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_RETENTION_AGE">${env:LOG_RETENTION_AGE:-15d}</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
            fileName="${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}"
            filePattern="${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE_NAME}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="${LOG_ROTATE_SIZE}"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="nomax">
                <Delete basePath="${LOG_PATH}" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="${LOG_FILE_NAME}-*.log.zip" />
                    <IfLastModified age="${LOG_RETENTION_AGE}" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.xxxx.yyyyy" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

application.properties
#logging properties
logging.file.path=/var/log/restapi/
logging.file.name=/var/log/restapi/restapi.log

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>restapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>restapi</name>
    <description>Restapi for eeee and zzzz</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.joschi.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

How can I stop logs from appearing in catalina.out and ensure that logs are only generated in the specified path in Log4j2 for my application?

A sure way to exclude spring-boot-starter-logging from all starters is to: 1. Add spring-boot-starter as an explicit dependency to your project 2. Exclude spring-boot-starter-logging from the spring-boot-starter dependency. s-b-s-logging is a transitive dependency of all starters, but only s-b-s has it as direct dependency.

I tried adding this to pom.xml:

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-logging



But I'm still facing the same error I mentioned above.

This question is similar to: How to stop application logs from logging into catalina.out in Tomcat. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Project Tree
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        ├── resources
        │   ├── application.properties
        │   ├── log4j2.xml
        │   └── logging.properties
        └── webapp
            └── WEB-INF

logging.properties
ADD logging.properties (IMPORTANT)
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=SEVERE

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-jsp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <!--
            <scope>provided</scope>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


build and install to Tomcat 9
Check Tomcat/logs no app output logging message.

